# How to compare two classifiers trained on different training sets?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, model-evaluation, resampling

I sampled a dataset A from the population D(e.g. a large cat-dog dataset). I first split A into training set 'A-train-1' and testing set 'A-test-1'. Then I trained a classifier 'X'(e.g. random forest) on A-train-1 and tested it on A-test-1. This gave me the test score 'score-X-A'.

A few days later, I want to train another classifier Y(e.g. LeNet model). This time I forgot that I have split A so I split it again into 'A-train-2' and 'A-test-2'. I trained Y on A-train-2 and test on A-test-2. This gives me the testing score 'score-Y-A'

Note that the train-test-2 dataset pairs are different from train-test-1. They may have different split ratio, different elements in training set and testing set since the random seed is not fixed when I split them.

Now the question is how to compare the classification ability of X and Y. **I guess it is not a good idea to directly compare score-X-A and score-Y-A since these scores are from different testing set**. What should I do? Can I resample another testing set 'Test-B' from population D ,which doesn't have overlap with A? Then I test X and Y on this Test-B and compare them based on the new scores? Or is there any other better, more valid method? Thank you!

Comment: Compare them how? You have two numbers and know how to say which is bigger. Do you need something beyond that for your comparison?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but as a practical matter couldn't you just re-train $Y$ on 'A-train-1'?

Comment: @Dave I do have two scores score-X-A and score-Y-A but they are not evaluated from the same testing set. Therefore it is not valid to compare them.

Comment: @whuber Well that's the best solution. However, sometimes the training may take too much computing resource and there may a lot of models to compare. Retraining all of them seems a kind of wasting resource. Most importantly, I am just curious about if there is a valid method to compare the models from different training set haha.

Comment: I figured as much.  It would be nice to know two details: were your splits into train+test at random?  Were the training sets the same size in both cases?

Comment: If I score a 90 in calculus and an 88 in physics, those are different tests, but I'd say that I scored higher on the calculus test. What about your situation makes it different from this?

Comment: @whuber Yes the dataset is split at random. Regarding the size of the training set, I would say they are different in the two cases. For example maybe the split ratio is 9vs1 for model X but 8vs2 for model Y

Comment: I think the question I do care is: Can I resample a new testing set from population that is specially used to compare the two model? I know this is not a conventional operation but is it valid?

Comment: @Dave Well I think a simple example is that there are two students A and B. A took a math final exam in 2019 and got 95. B took a math exam in 2020 and got 87. Can we say A is better at math than B? Maybe not, because the exam in 2019 is different from the exam in 2020!

Comment: Instead of an example, please say what about your problem makes it different from my setup with the calculus and physics tests.

Comment: @Dave You can say you got higher score in calculus than physics this time but you cannot say you are better at calculus than physics. Also I don't think your example here is much related to my question.

Comment: @Dave In you setup, the model is 'the student who takes the exam'. There are two testing set: 'calculus exam' and 'physics exam'. What you want to evaluate is on which testing set can the model performs better. However, in my question, there are two model: X and Y. What I want to evaluate is which model, X or Y, performs better on a certain tast(e.g. cat-dog classification).